# Regexp for a particular word with a digit

Tags: c++, regex

I just can't seems to come up with a regular expression for the following..

a particular word, i.e. `Earth` + any digit.

An example would be,

```
Earth1
Earth2
Earth3
Earth10
Earth20
...
```

I thought this should work but it does not..

```
std::regex("Earth\d$")
```

Comment: Is there a cap on # of digits? If not,

`"Earth[\d]+"` might work better, as this would require 1 or more digits after the word Earth.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firstly, you have to add a slash to escape the current slash. Secondly - add repetition (`+`) as `\d` means digit (and not a number):

```
std::regex("Earth\\d+$")
```

Comment: I assume you want to match "Earth123" but not "MotherEarth456", in which case you'd want to add "^" at the beginning